# JBOSS 5.1 AS - An application server may already be running on host localhost

Tags: jboss, server, jboss5.x

I am using Kepler. JBoss 5.1 AS - When i start the server i am getting the error. " An application server may already be running on host localhost." I even killed the java in task manager and restarted .

Message = > Web poller found a running server at url http://localhost:8080

Comment: and below the message  .. the other thing its saying as -"would you launch a new instance or .... " in a radio button